# Share to social network generated content to a client (Use React)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-share

I encountered the problem of sharing social networks with a chained image on the client, I use react-share for this. But it requires in the parameters to write absolute paths for the picture. I’m trying to understand how to take and save a picture in a folder on the server.

Comment: *What* server? React is generally used on the client side.

Comment: I mean that react, I generate an image to share on social networks, I have to get this generated image in my folder so that I have an absolute path to it. Sorry for my English